# Get Last Column in Each Different Customer ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Invoice Date and Customer ID (among other data, of course).  I'm looking to display the longest invoice date in the future in the table for each customer.

I am currently using this MySQL in the WHERE:

```
WHERE o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date = (SELECT MAX(o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date) FROM o70vm_invoices_invoices)";
```

This code currently displays the oldest date in the column for just one customer.

I'm including my entire MySQL query below, please keep in mind that I'm having to pull from various tables to display the data I need.

```
$query = "SELECT       
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.name AS 'Parent_Name',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.id AS 'Parent_ID',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.company AS 'Children',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.active AS 'Active',

    o70vm_invoices_invoices.id AS 'Invoice_ID',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.user_id AS 'Parent_ID_on_Invoice',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_num AS 'Invoice_Num',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date AS 'Invoice_Date',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_duedate AS 'Invoice_Date_Due',

    o70vm_invoices_payments.invoice_id,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.id,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_amount AS 'Payment_Amount',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_datetime AS 'Payment_Date',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_duedate,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_status AS 'Payment_Status',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_description AS 'Payment_Descript',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_type AS 'Payment_Type'

    FROM o70vm_invoices_invoices, o70vm_invoices_contacts, o70vm_invoices_payments
    WHERE
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.id = o70vm_invoices_invoices.user_id
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_payments.invoice_id = o70vm_invoices_invoices.id
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date < '2099-01-01'
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.active = 1
    AND o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date = (SELECT MAX(o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date) FROM o70vm_invoices_invoices)";
```

If I use a GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY o70vm_invoices_contacts.id
```

I can pull each customer to display but it does not display the last future invoice in the table.

Based on Stefan's comments below, here is my revised subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT   *
FROM   ( SELECT 
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.name AS 'Parent_Name',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.id AS 'Parent_ID',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.company AS 'Children',
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.active AS 'Active',

    o70vm_invoices_invoices.id AS 'Invoice_ID2',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.user_id AS 'Parent_ID_on_Invoice',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_num AS 'Invoice_Num',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date AS 'Invoice_Date',
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_duedate AS 'Invoice_Date_Due',

    o70vm_invoices_payments.invoice_id,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.id,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_amount AS 'Payment_Amount',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_datetime AS 'Payment_Date',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_duedate,
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_status AS 'Payment_Status',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_description AS 'Payment_Descript',
    o70vm_invoices_payments.payment_type AS 'Payment_Type'

    FROM o70vm_invoices_invoices, o70vm_invoices_contacts, o70vm_invoices_payments
    WHERE
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.id = o70vm_invoices_invoices.user_id
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_payments.invoice_id = o70vm_invoices_invoices.id
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date < '2099-01-01'
    AND
    o70vm_invoices_contacts.active = 1
    ORDER BY o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date DESC

    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY tmp.id";
```

This query lists the first invoice date and not the last invoice date.  If I change the order to ASC, it just sorts the results of the first invoice date.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Best way might be to make use of a sub query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM o70vm_invoices_invoices 
    ORDER BY invoice_date DESC
) AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.id
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, this gives me the first date in all the customers. So very close.

Comment: then just sort the pther way around in the sub query

Comment: That's what I thought too.  When I change the sort, it just sorts the first dates in the column per customer from ASC or DESC, not getting the furthest date.  Two thumbs up for sticking with me.

Comment: Well, I just checked it and the query works fine in the way that for each customer it lists only the invoice that is the newest (in the sense that the one with the highest timestamp value would be considered the newest one, so also future values are possible). The query does what I intended it to do. But maybe I misinterpreted your question ?

Comment: No, you got my question right.  I must implemented your code incorrectly.  I've adjusted my question to reflect my current subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this; however, this works.

I just added MAX inside my query as such:

```
max(o70vm_invoices_invoices.invoice_date) AS 'Invoice_Date',
```

and this lists the furthest date for each customer.